# Undefined variable error in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_class.php
        on line 20
Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\test_class.php
        on line 20
```

I get the above error when i use this piece of code for checking down my username and password with my database.

```
<?php
    class test_class {

        public function __construct() { 

        }
        public function doLogin() {

            include("connection.php");

            if (isset($_POST['username']))
                {
                $username= $_POST['username'];
                }
                if (isset($_POST['password']))
                {
                $password= $_POST['password'];
                } 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
            if(!$result)

            {

            return 'assa';

            }else{

            return 'assa112121212';

            }

                }
        }
?>
```

Comment: "Little Bobby Tables, we call him". ;)

Comment: I think those return values are awesome!

Comment: Never do things like this "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'"!

Comment: Macbirdie is pointing out that this code is subject to SQL injection attacks. As soon as you have a user/pass in the db, try logging in with the username   ' or 1=1 --  Fix this by using bound parameters in your sql query and not by appending strings.

Comment: wrt sql injection, this script might help: http://programanddesign.com/php/sql-injection-safe-queries-redux/

Comment: Readers: note the page Mark links to shows an outdated method of protecting against injection. The more modern way is to use prepared statements, which keep the data separate from the statement. Prepared statements have other advantages, such as being more performant when executed multiple times.

Comment: Just a little note, the question was never answered: 
the problem was $username and $password were defined in the if statements and were therefore encapsulated, so they no longer exist once the if statements are completed. Define $username and $password outside the if statements and that should fix the issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This means, most likely, that your form hasn't been submitted. You should make sure that you only use the variables if they exist. Furthermore, you should [never ever](http://xkcd.com/327/) use the input from users without validating it. Try the following, for example:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT *
                      FROM users
                      WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'
                      AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."'";
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    # ...
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: He fixed the problem and brought some extra security issues to his attention. Whoever assassinated this post should be banned for having such a stupid opinion on it.

Answer (score 10):

This is just a **notice** that the variables are being referenced in the query without being in scope.

Define $username and $password at the top of doLogin() and initialized them to Null or similar. Then check for them later.

You also seem to be executing the query regardless of $username and $password being set. You should do something more like:

```
if( isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
     //create vars, do query
}else{
     // Nothing to process
}
```

Both errors occur on line 20, which I assume is the query string interpolation. The issues here are:

1. inconsistent scope/referencing (which sucks in PHP anyway)
2. Your ifs need to be a bit more orderly. This error is small, but worse ones will bite you in the bum later if you handle variables like this :)

Also: **escape your variables before dumping them like hot coals into your SQL**
see PDO (which I would go for) or mysql_escape_string()

**good luck**!

Comment: @Mike: A salt is used when hashing a password, which isnt mentioned in the question. Good answer though +1

Comment: @Sam152, Thanks :) Also, I now have 1,234 points which is cool.

Answer (score 3):

One more happy class and bug free :)

```
<?php
class test_class
{
    private $post = array();
    public function __construct ()
    {
    }
    public function doLogin ()
    {
        $this->post = $_POST;
        include ("connection.php");
        if ($this->post['username'] && $this->post['password']) {
            $username = $this->post['username'];
            $password = $this->post['password'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
            if (! $result) {
                return 'assa';
            } else {
                return 'assa112121212';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
class test_class {

    public function doLogin() {
        include("connection.php");

        if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $query = "SELECT * ".
                     "FROM users " .
                     "WHERE username = '$username' ".
                     "  AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
            if(!$result) {
               return 'assa';
            } else {
               return 'assa112121212';
            }
        } else {
            echo "Missing parameter 'username' and/or 'password'";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should [escape](http://se.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) *$username* and *$password* to avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You are also checking the database whether or not a username and password are supplied.

Perhaps something like this;

```
public function doLogin() {

    include("connection.php");
    $username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : NULL ;
    $password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : NULL ;
        if ( $username !== NULL && $password !== NULL )  {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
                    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
            /* auth code here */

        } else {
        return false; // no u/p provided    
    }

    }
```

You should also be escaping your inputs before putting them anywhere near your database, either by using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or [PDO (PHP Data Objects)](http://php.net/pdo)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); from the page Sam linked to. Notices are really unnecessary, and are like using WALL and WERROR flags with gcc.

Comment: -Wall and E_NOTICE are very necessary. They warn you when you are being a moron, which can potentially lead to an hour over a hot debugger :) for a bit of extra output, for me, it is worth it.

Comment: but in this case, E_NOTICE completely stops something from working when really it shouldn't. at least a program with -Wall complaining.